# How can i pass only one message for all fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

This is code of register function which generate error of success and failure.

```html
public function register(Request $request) {    
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
              [ 
              'user_type' => 'required',
              'fname' => 'required',
              'lname' => 'required',
              'dob' => 'required',
              'phone' => 'required',
              'gender' => 'required',
              'uname' => 'required',
              'email' => 'required|email',
              'password' => 'required',  
              'c_password' => 'required|same:password', 
             ]);   
 if ($validator->fails()) {          
       return response()->json(['failed'=>$validator->errors()], 401);                        }    
 $input = $request->all();  
 $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
 $user = User::create($input); 
 $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
 $success['status'] = true;
 $success['data'] = [$user];
 $success['message'] ="User created successfully!";
 
    //  return response()->json([
    //     "message" => " record created"
    // ], 201);
 return response()->json($success, $this->successStatus); 
}
```

This is my output[image]

1.All error message show in one line..This is my main point..But i want to actually this message of This image...How can i do that?
2.Second thing in API if any user put same email id api give json error not laravel error..

[image]

Comment: just return that message as the 'failed'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return response()->json(['status'=> False, 'msg' => 'This is not successful'], 401);
```

You can pass custom json in response instead of validator response.

For checking if email exists update the validation like this:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
```

where `users` is your table name and `email` is your column name

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your code

```
if ($validator->fails()) {          
   return response()->json(['failed'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
```

with

```
if ($validator->fails()) {          
   return response()->json(['status'=> 'False', 'msg' => 'This is not sccessfully'], 401);
```